# Git: take backup of a single branch in another branch

Tags: git, git-branch

We have a git branch named `dev/theme`. Now we are not able to create a new branch named as `dev`.

We want to take a backup of `dev/theme` just in case we need it and delete this branch so that we are able to create a new branch name `dev`.

How to take a backup of the `dev/theme` branch in another git branch?

Comment: Note that to do a backup, it makes more sense to use tags instead of branches. Create a new tag and use a meaningful name each time you want to "update" the backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 git checkout -b mybackup dev/theme // this creates a branch mybackup that points on the same place as dev/theme
 git branch // to check yourself
```

Note however, that branches in git are just pointers to a commit, so you're not really duplicating anything, but creating another pointer to the last commit (of dev/theme branch in this case)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch out of dev/theme and it will be independent of dev/theme and can serve as the backup

Comment: should I take pull of dev/theme in this new branch?

Comment: Just checkout to dev/theme and create a new branch by git checkout -b <new_branch_name>. Then push the branch to remote server (git push origin <new_branch_name>). It should work fine. (push is not mandatory. It will only make sure that backup is copied on server as well incase local screws up)